# Does this mean anything? 私たちはしておりません

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

This is an interview with Hiroshi Yamauchi. I can never understand even 1 sentence he says in any interviews he ever does.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcrvjSjWmPM&t=0m56s

32ビットを意識して、値段を決めるってことは私たちはしておりません。

I think he's saying something about Nintendos role in the 32 bit era. Maybe he's saying nintendo didn't play a part in that era because they skipped this era or something.

Answer (score 2):

32ビットを意識して値段を決める means "to determine the price (of our console) taking '32-bit' into consideration" (remove that comma if it is confusing you). ってこと (=ということ) is a nominalizer, and は right after it is a topic particle [marking the **object** of する](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23378/5010).

> 「32ビットを意識して値段を決める」ってことは私たちはしておりません。
>   We do not do (things like) "determining the price taking '32-bit' into consideration".

This '32-bit' might be a reference to the rival console (PS1), but I think he was just saying the number of bits itself is not important.

Comment: Thanks! I was not expecting a reply, to be honest. This sentence was extremely confusing for me. I've watched that video for over 2 years now and still had no clue what he was even trying to say. But now, based on your reply and looking at the context of the video, it seems natural he is talking about financial/economics aspect of the video game industry, seeing as the video is full of business jargon and finance charts and stuff.

Comment: @SomaRise His pronunciation is not clear (due to his age), but I think his logic is not difficult to understand.