# What does はもってmean in this conversation?

Tags: grammar, meaning

A: コートをもっていますか？
B: ええ、もっています。
A: じゃ、せびろももっていますか？
B: いいえ、せびろ**はもって**いません。

Comment: there is no はもって, just は+もっていません

Answer (score 1):

This は (pronounced as *wa*) is the topic-marking particle. もって is the te-form of もつ, and is a part of もっていません ("(I) do not have").

In the last sentence, せびろ ("a suit") is the object of もっていません ("I don't have"), but は must be used instead of を, because せびろ is being contrasted with the previous topic (コート). If B said せびろ**を**もっていません in this context, it would sound awfully unnatural to Japanese ears.

See also:

- [Japanese with Anime - Contrastive *wa*](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/07/contrastive-wa.html)
- [Particle は replacing を - where does the stress lie?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14708/5010)
- [Why can は and を sometimes be used interchangeably?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23378/5010)