# かのじょはブルスが生きさせる。

Tags: grammar, word-choice, translation, verbs

I see a book saying let and make are the meaning of せる. However, I see that "enable" is a synonym of let and make. So I wonder if these statements are similar, in the meaning of かのじょはブルスが生きさせる。

> She makes Brews live.
>   She lets Brews live.
>   She makes Brews want to live.
>   She lets Brews want live.
>   She is Brews' will to live. (willpower)
>   She enables Brews' will to live.
>   She enables Brews' to live.
>   She is Brews' intention to live.
>   She is why Brews lives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

彼女【かのじょ】はブルスが生きさせる means "Brews makes/lets her live" or "Brews enables her to live". Whether to use "make/let" or "enable" depends on the context (ie, whether "she" wants to die or live).

This sentence is semantically the same as ブルスが彼女を生きさせる.

- が is the subject marker, so Brews is the one who does the action (=to make/let/allow someone (to) live).
- は is the topic marker, and [it can often replace を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17817/5010). Because there is another subject (ブルス) which is clearly marked with が, "彼女は" will be interpreted as the *object* of the action (ie, the one who is made/allowed to live)