# The meaning and nuance behind the phrase "話は通してある"

Tags: meaning, particle-は, word-usage

> 話は通してある

This is a phrase I've come across a few times recently in manga.

For example:

> 「ユキにも話は通してある」

I'm not familiar with it so I'm not quite sure of it's correct meaning and usage, looking online I've only managed to find a meaning for the phrase: "話を通して"  - with the を particle instead of the は - which means to "get it explained to…/run it by…" with the nuance of getting consent from somebody.

How does 話は通してある differ? Does it have a similar or even the same meaning as 話を通して? Or if it 話は通してある has a different meaning completely, will someone kindly explain?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It has roughly the same meaning as 話を通してある. The key here is that you can replace を with は when the object is focused or contrasted. It's a general grammatical rule.

Related questions:

- [Why can は and を sometimes be used interchangeably?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23378/5010)
- ["は + verb" instead of "を + verb"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17817/5010)
- [Particle は replacing を - where does the stress lie?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14708/5010)