# What's the difference between saying 私は日本語を話しません vs 私は日本語が話しません?

Tags: grammar, negation

> 私は日本語を話しません
>
> 私は日本語が話しません

I've seen both versions on the Internet. Maybe only one is the correct version? Maybe both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

日本語が話しません is ungrammatical. It sounds very unnatural. The following is the summary of what is OK and what is not:

> - 私は日本語**を**話しません: OK
> - 私は日本語**は**話しません: OK
> - 私は日本語**が**話しません: **Wrong!**
> - 私は日本語**を**話せません: OK
> - 私は日本語**は**話せません: OK
> - 私は日本語**が**話せません: OK

話す is a transitive verb (like English "speak"), so basically its object must be marked with を. But there are several exceptions you have to consider.

- Exception (1): When the object is decorated by the topic marker, をは turns into は (or は replaces を).

  - [は is used for Objective 格助詞](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52336/5010)
  - [Particle は replacing を - where does the stress lie?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14708/5010)
  - [What is the subject of this sentence? Is it the book (mentioned) or the author (who is not mentioned)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17571/5010)
- Exception  (2): When the verb is potential, the object can be marked with が, too. (話せる is the potential form of 話す)

  - [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010)
- Exception  (3): Using two は in one sentence is [fine in a negative sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1077/5010). 私は日本語は話します is still grammatical, but the second は will have a strong contrastive meaning.

Answer (score 2):

私は日本語を話しません means "I don't speak Japanese". 日本語が話しません is unnatural because this が is the subject marker, so it means "Japanese language doesn't speak". However 日本語は話しません make sense.

This usage of は is the contrastive-marker function. The difference of が and は is already explained in this. [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%e3%81%af-and-ga-%e3%81%8c)