# 日本語は話せますか, 日本語が話せますか and 日本語を話せますか what's the difference?

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-を

> 日本語は話せますか

> 日本語が話せますか

> 日本語を話せますか

What's the difference? Some people said it means the same thing, but when I googled it several people were saying several different things and I'm lost. I read that 日本語を話せますか seems a little bit sudden in a conversation so it's better to use 日本語は話せますか but when Japanese is not a new topic, 日本語を話せますか is more natural.

Comment: Hello @Rodrigo, welcome to Japanese Stackexchange! Regarding the difference between the second and the third sentence, please check out [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/609/the-difference-between-%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%82%92-with-the-potential-form-of-a-verb).

Please note that before posting a new question, you can (and are encouraged to) search it with the search bar at the top, because it's possible that someone has asked it before and there's already a bunch of answers and an open discussion about it.

Comment: I see two different aspects in your question. First, the replacement of を or が by は, and second, the difference between を and が with potential verbs such as 話せる. I suggest tackling both concerns separately.

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58348/32952