# Confusion on は being used

Tags: particle-は

So the sentence is " そういう相手は力で叩き潰して教えるに限る" which translates to "people like you need to be crushed by force." I'm confused on why it isn't written as"そういう相手を"。If は is used could it also be translated as "people like you should crush (things) by force"

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14708/5010 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48051/5010 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17817/5010 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52336/5010

Comment: no those only have a food item and I'm talking about something that can actually be doing an action versus the action being done to them

Comment: Who said this only applies to food? 寿司は食べません means the action of eating being done to sushi. Specifically, please read [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/48054/5010).

Comment: Still not what I'm looking for. If you look at my example sentence the translation is people like you shouldn't be crushed by force. With Dakshin being done to that person. But it can also be translated a different way. It can be translated to people like you should destroy (things) by force. None of the examples you showed clarify that