# 止める and 止まる being used equally

Tags: transitivity

Last year, on Lang-8, I wrote a text and there was the following sentence there:

> 英語を作文するは止まるのだ。

I tried to mean "**I** will stop to write English texts (on Lang-8)".

I have got two corrections:

> 1. 英語を作文するのが止まります。
> 2. 英語で書くのは（作文するのは）止めます。

Once that I tried to mean that I will stop to write in English there, is it possible to use the first sentence, with the intransitive verb 止まる, in this case? Does that sentence mean something like "it'll be stopped to write English"? Maybe my *original sentence in Japanese* confused the corrector. The second correction, with the implied subject, that is me, sounds grammatically natural to me. I know the idea of transitivity but I got confused with these two sentences.

Besides, I have read around there that the direct object of a verb can be the topic of the sentence, switching を to は. Can I say that `英語で書くのは止めます。` and `英語で書くのを止めます。` are, at least grammatically, the same? If so, are both commonly used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the latter one seems legitimate to me. I think you have failed to clarify the meaning when you posted the incorrect Japanese sentence.

英語で書くのは止めます and 英語で書くのを止めます are both grammatically correct sentences, but they are slightly different in meaning:

- [The meaning and nuance behind the phrase "話は通してある"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48051/5010)
- [Particle は replacing を - where does the stress lie?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14708/5010)
- ["は + verb" instead of "を + verb"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17817/5010)
- [Why can は and を sometimes be used interchangeably?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23378/5010)