# The particle は before 押す

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-を

> スイッチ**は**押しましたか。

Can を be used in place of は here? *(Have you pressed the switch? / Did you press the switch?)*

押す is a transitive verb, so the use of は is confusing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also related: [“は + verb” instead of “を + verb”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17817/5010) / [Particle は replacing を - where does the stress lie?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14708/5010) / [The difference between は and を?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49081/5010)